# Strange color behavior with Graphics2D setColor

Tags: java, awt, paint, graphics2d

I´m taking an image and painting a rectangle over, but the problem is that with some images the rectangle  color is fine but with others the color changes. How can I fix such behavior

this is my code

```
public class Index {
static int[][] coordenadas = new int[1][4];
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    coordenadas[0][0]=530;
    coordenadas[0][1]=237;
    coordenadas[0][2]=86;
    coordenadas[0][3]=17;
    //File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Juan\\Desktop\\2.jpg");
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Juan\\Desktop\\1.jpg");
    paint(file);
}

public static void paint(File file) throws IOException{
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
    Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();    
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);            
    //g.drawRect(coordenadas[0][0], coordenadas[0][2], coordenadas[0][2], coordenadas[0][3]);           
   g.fillRect(coordenadas[0][0], coordenadas[0][3], coordenadas[0][2], coordenadas[0][3]);



    g.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(img,"jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\Juan\\Desktop\\outcome.jpg"));   
}
}
```

this is an example of the 2 differents outputs

Worng output

[image: Worng output]

Rigth output

[image: Rigth output]

These are the links for the original images

http://imageshack.com/a/img661/1940/bqwmPL.jpg

http://imageshack.com/a/img903/1447/vDwVtf.jpg

Thanks in advance for your time and aswers

Comment: a few mistakes (everything is in Oracle tutorial Graphics2D) 1. never to load Image nor File inside intensive paint, 2. use paintComponent or paintIcon is better in this case and 3. coordenadas should be rellative not harcoded value

Comment: Hi mr @mKorbel thanks for your comment, coordenadas is relative I just posted here with hardcoded values for show the purpose. About usage of paintComponent or paintIcon I don´t understand how to use in my objective, Do you have any suggestion how to load the image from the disk. Im using this method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Following the sugestion of @mrKobel I´ve changed the way of load the image, from file to ImageIcon, and all works. this the  new code.

```
public class Index {

static int[][] coordenadas = new int[1][4];
static BufferedImage bi ;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    coordenadas[0][0]=530;
    coordenadas[0][1]=237;
    coordenadas[0][2]=86;
    coordenadas[0][3]=17;   
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Juan\\Desktop\\2.jpg");       
     BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight(),  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
     Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
     img.paintIcon(null, g2d, 0, 0);
     Color color = new Color(255,255,0,100);
     g2d.setColor(color);               
     g2d.fillRect(coordenadas[0][0], coordenadas[0][1], coordenadas[0][2], coordenadas[0][3]);      
     ImageIO.write( image,"jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\Juan\\Desktop\\outcome.jpg"));   


}


}
```